# How to clean up messy nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an office_listing model that has a neighborhood_id and a city_id. Since the listing model needs both ids to be created, I've set up the following routes:

```
resources :cities do
  resources :neighborhoods do
    resources :office_listings
```

That's the only way I know how to give the context of the neighborhood and city ids to the 'new' cotroller action. I don't want to force the user to select the neighborhood and city from a form when he has already navigated to the create listing page from a neighb/city. Is there any other way to pass such a context to the new page without such a long url (neighborhood/id/city/id/office_listing/new)? I'm planning on adding a viewing which requires an office listing id, so things are only going to get more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [`shallow: true`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to cut down on the length of the urls. It doesn't solve the issues that nesting can bring about, but it does clean up your routes.

```
resources :cities, shallow: true do
  resources :neighborhoods do
    resources :office_listings
```

This is also something that you can't mix. So you can't have some routes as shallow, others as not-shallow. It's an all or nothing condition.